# android:fontFamily not recognized in Android Studio

Tags: android, dialog

I am trying to implement the Dialog tutorial on Android developer website (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) using Android Studio on Mac OSX. Everything is fine except for the font of the hint. Here is a picture below in the Design View:

[image]

I am unable to run it on my device as i get the following error:

```
Gradle: No resource identifier found for attribute 'fontFamily' in package 'android'
```

Here is the xml code which is the same as on the developer's website

```
<TextView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="ID"
    android:textSize="8pt"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:hint="enter your username"
/>
<TextView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="PIN"
    android:textSize="8pt"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:hint="enter your password" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android you should use `android:typeface="serif"` instead.

Android on itself only has 3 default fonts:

- normal (Droid Sans)
- serif (Droid Serif)
- monospace (Droid Sans Mono)

Comment: thanks..but all of the three above do not change the font of the hint. It remains the same as in the picture in the question

Comment: @stud91 sorry, you can't change type face of hint, you only can change type face of content value

Comment: okay..in the documentation here (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) it says "you should change its font family to "sans-serif" so that both text fields use a matching font style". So there is no way we can make the font consistent?